# 3D 360 degree Rotating Images in android studio implementation

Tags: android, image, 3d, multi-touch, image-rotation

I have Tried :
[3D image in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9962666/3d-image-in-android)

[Problem in rotating image in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944588/problem-in-rotating-image-in-android)

[Resize image while rotating image in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593211/resize-image-while-rotating-image-in-android)

[Rotating image in Google map in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442444/rotating-image-in-google-map-in-android)

[rotate image in android imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134236/rotate-image-in-android-imageview)

and also Google.

But i cant find any tutorial or example or any video tutorials that teaches me how to use **3D 360 degree rotating images on user touch.**

Can Anyone help me with this. suggest any good tutorial or video links is most welcome.

Comment: It would help if you could describe what you mean by '3D 360 degree Rotation Image' as you've linked to a number of SO solutions but haven't explained how any of them DON'T do what you are looking for.